# Unable to login with correct username and password php and myql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello every one i'm new to php. I was just trying to create a multi users login system. In the first approach i get what is required but whenever i try to login with wrong username or password. else statement echos multiple times. but in the second approach i get the last statement executed every time i try to login even with correct username and password.

**This is the first approach**

```
    if(isset($_POST['signin'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query = "SELECT * from `users`;";
        if(count(fetchAll($query))>0){
            foreach(fetchAll($query) as $row){
              if($username==$row["username"]&&$password==$row["password"]&&$row["type"]=="admin"){
                  echo  "Admin";
              }elseif($username==$row["username"]&&$password==$row["password"]&&$row["type"]=="teacher"){
                echo "Teacher";
            }elseif($username==$row["username"]&&$password==$row["password"]&&$row["type"]=="student"){
                echo  "Student";
             }else{
                  echo "Username or password not found!";
              }
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Unknown Error')</script>";

        }
    }
```

**and this is second one**

```
if(isset($_POST['signin'])){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $admin_query = "SELECT * from `users` where username = '$username' and password = '$password' and type = 'admin';";
            $teacher_query = "SELECT * from `users` where username = '$username' and password = '$password' and type = 'teacher';";
            $student_query = "SELECT * from `users` where username = '$username' and password = '$password' and type = 'student';";
            if(performQuery($admin_query==1)){
                echo "Admin";

            }elseif(performQuery($teacher_query==1)){
                echo "Teacher";

            }elseif(performQuery($student_query==1)){
                echo "Student";

            }else{
                echo "No user found ";
            }
}
```

The performQuery function is

```
function performQuery($query){
    $con = new PDO(DBINFO,DBUSER,DBPASS);
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: first are you using PDO or mysqli ?

Comment: I'm using PDO in this case

Comment: what is `performQuery`?

Comment: `function performQuery($query){
    $con = new PDO(DBINFO,DBUSER,DBPASS);
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}`

Comment: Edit your question as well, so other have a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
            $con = mysqli_connect('');// taking as your connection query

            $username = "whatever";//taking as user input
            $password = "Password";//taking as user input

            //By using direct data in SQL login query you are subject to SQL injection. Please Make sure to use prepared statements.

            $admin_query = "SELECT * from `users` where username = '$username' and password = '$password' and type = 'admin';";
            $teacher_query = "SELECT * from `users` where username = '$username' and password = '$password' and type = 'teacher';";
            $student_query = "SELECT * from `users` where username = '$username' and password = '$password' and type = 'student';";

            // by using oop approch
            if($con->query($admin_query)){
                echo "Admin";

            }elseif($con->query($teacher_query)){
                echo "Teacher";

            }elseif($con->query($student_query)){
                echo "Student";

            }else{
                echo "No user found ";
            }

            // by using procedural  approch
            if(mysqli_query($con,$admin_query)){
                echo "Admin";

            }elseif(mysqli_query($con,$teacher_query)){
                echo "Teacher";

            }elseif(mysqli_query($con,$student_query)){
                echo "Student";

            }else{
                echo "No user found ";
            }
?>
```

Note: Use a prepared statement to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

First, when you are using database query try to bind the parameters instead of concatenation to your query because it will lead to [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Now as your code state that your are passing boolean to your **performQuery** function instead of query

`performQuery($admin_query==1)` will lead to `performQuery(false)` as `$admin_query` is not equal to 1.  That's why your query is failing.

If you print the **$query** in your function you will find it out.

So, you have to remove that check inside the param. The code will be like this

```
        if(performQuery($admin_query)){
            echo "Admin";

        }elseif(performQuery($teacher_query)){
            echo "Teacher";

        }elseif(performQuery($student_query)){
            echo "Student";

        }else{
            echo "No user found ";
        }


        function performQuery($query){
            try {    
                $con = new PDO(DBINFO,DBUSER,DBPASS);
                $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    if($stm->fetchColumn()){
                        return true;
                    }
                }else{
                   echo 'Error -> ';
                   var_dump($st->errorInfo());
                   echo '<br/>Query -> ';
                   var_dump($query);
                }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                echo 'Exception -> ';
                var_dump($e->getMessage());
                echo '<br/>Query -> ';
                var_dump($query);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: First i tried this way but still getting same output

Comment: @VikramKhan edited my answer and added some exception handling in `performQuery` function